# What is the `.xts` constructor/how does it work?

Tags: r, xts

I am familiar with `as.xts` and `xts` as ways to create an `xts` object. I have just come across `.xts` as used in the following:

```
> x <- .xts(1:3,60*1:3)
> is.xts(x)
[1] TRUE
> x
                    [,1] 
1970-01-01 01:01:00    1
1970-01-01 01:02:00    2
1970-01-01 01:03:00    3
```

However, I can't find anything about it in the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/xts.pdf). I note that the same arguments as in the example above would not work for `as.xts` or `xts`.

Is `.xts` some kind of standard R construction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `.xts` is not any kind of standard.  `.xts` is mainly for internal use, but it's exported for convenience.  `.xts` differs from `xts` in that `xts` requires `order.by` be time-based, whereas `.xts` expects `index` (its second argument, akin to `order.by`) to be numeric.

This is because the `index` attribute of xts objects is stored internally as a numeric vector with `tclass` and `tzone` attributes.